# cannot find Go package

Tags: go

I am new at learning Go. I read that if I create a package and I use the install function that, that package will be available throughout my program. Yet after creating the following package and running the 'go install' command the package is not available to my program:

```
package person

import (
 "fmt"
 "time"
)

//Person struct
type Person struct {
 FirstName, LastName string
 Dob                 time.Time
 Email, Location     string
}

//PrintName method
func (p Person) PrintName() {
  fmt.Printf("\n%s %s\n", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
}

//PrintDetails Method
func (p Person) PrintDetails() {
  fmt.Printf("[Date of Birth: %s, Email: %s, Location: %s ]\n", p.Dob.String(), p.Email,
    p.Location)
}
```

and then creating the following main function either gives me 'syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body' or it says the package is not found if I only use the package name which is what I learned I can do

```
package main

import (
"person"
)

p := Person {
FirstName : "Shiju",
LastName : "Varghese",
Dob : time.Date(1979, time.February, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
Email : "shiju@email.com",
Location : "Kochi",
}

p. PrintName()
p. PrintDetails()
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: If both of your snippets are `.go` files within the same directory then you already have the definition for person in your second file.

Comment: Like I said I am new and do not understand what the error means. I am creating an instance of a struct and make it do something. The files are not in the same folder

Comment: I highly recommend taking the Tour of Go. It comes with all the boilerplate properly set up and you can get your feet wet with the language without too much ado. Also not that running `go install` is never needed. Do not assume things, e.g. go install has nothing to do with whether you can or cannot use a package in an other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`non declartion statement outside function body` refers to this part of your code

```
p := Person {
FirstName : "Shiju",
LastName : "Varghese",
Dob : time.Date(1979, time.February, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
Email : "shiju@email.com",
Location : "Kochi",
}

p. PrintName()
p. PrintDetails()
```

you need to put that insde some function, `main` function for instance.
also when you initiate a type, you need to refer it by its package name, for example, `me:=person.Person{}`, that should take care of `type Person not found`. If you are calling a type or function within the same package you don't need to do that. If its the same package, you will not need to `import` it either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this explains it and solves my problem. Detail for newbies is a blessing

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help to solve your problem. If you want to declare your person outside of the function you should use var as well as you cant use methods outside of the functions

```
package main

import (
    "person"
)

var p person.Person = Person {
 FirstName : "Shiju",
 LastName : "Varghese",
 Dob : time.Date(1979, time.February, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
 Email : "shiju@email.com",
 Location : "Kochi",
}

func main(){
   p.PrintName()
   p.PrintDetails()   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the proper way to import a local package and use it would be

```
import person "./dirnameOfPackage"

func main(){
    var p Person
    p.FirstName = "yourName"
    p.LastName = "lastname"
}
```